Asymptotic behavior of $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{n-k+1}$ as $n$ goes to $+\infty$
I am in front of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{n-k+1}$.
I find no way to evaluate it in closed form. Is there any?
Is there a way to find an equivalent as $n$ goes to infinity?

For an approximation:  Find the largest term.  Find how many terms either side before they get much smaller.

Long comment
This is sequence $A003101$ in $OEIS$.
Answering this question, @leonbloy provided an extremely good approximation
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{n-k+1}$$
$$\log (S_n) \approx (n+2-x_0) \log(x_0) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left({\frac{2 \pi}{n+1+x_0}}\right)$$ where
$$x_0=\frac{n+1}{W(e (n+1))}=\frac 1e e^{W(e (n+1))}$$ $W(.)$ being Lambert function.
Checking, if $n>7$ the maximum relative error for $S_n$ is smaller than $0.05$% and smaller than $0.02$% if $n >111$.
A few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & S_n \\
 10 & 49845 & 49863 \\
 15 & 190691716 & 190780212 \\
 20 & 2281724622065 & 2282779990494 \\
 25 & 66042622781960110 &   66071772829247409 \\
 30 & 3938037218650692634194 &    3939676100069476203757 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

It is unlikely the a closed form exists, but we can calculate some asymptotics. Observe that the largest term is the $k\approx n/\log(n)$ term, which has size $\exp((1+o(1))n\log(n))$. Since there are at most $n = \exp(\log(n))$ terms, we have that the sum is asymptotically equal to $\exp((1+o(1))n\log(n))$. One could calculate more precise asymptotics, but that takes some work and you should ask yourself why you need them in the first place.
